# Returning within a finally block in a generator, hides the exception

Tags: python, generator

In the Python `return` docs [it says](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement): "In a generator function, the `return` statement indicates that the generator is done and will cause `StopIteration` to be raised."

In the following example, if we return in a `finally` block while an exception is active, the exception is suppressed and a `StopIteration` is raised instead. Is it expected for the exception to be suppressed? Is there a way to `return` from within a `finally` block without suppressing it?

```py
def hello(do_return):
    try:
        yield 2
        raise ValueError
    finally:
        print('done')
        if do_return:
            return
```

Calling without `return`:

```py
>>> h = hello(False)
>>> next(h)
Out[68]: 2
>>> next(h)
done
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-69-31146b9ab14d>", line 1, in <module>
    next(h)
  File "<ipython-input-63-73a2e5a5ffe8>", line 4, in hello
    raise ValueError
ValueError
```

Calling with `return`:

```py
>>> h = hello(True)
>>> next(h)
Out[71]: 2
>>> next(h)
done
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-72-31146b9ab14d>", line 1, in <module>
    next(h)
StopIteration
```

Comment: `return` and exception are two different control mechanisms. You can either `return` without an exception, or you can have an exception, but then the `return` will not be executed. You can not have both at the same time.

Comment: Yes, I know they are different control mechanisms, but I'm not sure how it's relevant to the question? Normally if you return in a `finally` block the active exception is still raised when the function exits, unlike in the generator where the active exception is suppressed.

Comment: There is no "normal" return from your function. The function always terminates by raising an exception. The keyword `return` in your example is essentially a disguise for `raise StopIteration`. When an exception (StopIteration) is raised while another exception (ValueError) is handled, the second exception prevails.

Comment: Ok, that's what I wanted to hear, if it is well known and expected that in a generator a return will basically suppress the existing exception, unlike a normal function. If you just write it as a answer I'll accept it. 

Partially I wanted to ask the question so others with the same issue find it because it was quite unexpected for a exception to be quietly ignored like this when I encountered it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "normal" return from your function. Your function always terminates by raising an exception. The keyword `return` in your example is essentially a disguise for `raise StopIteration`, not a return as such. When an exception (`StopIteration`) is raised while another exception (`ValueError`) is handled, the second exception prevails.